# Pyshark read all values from a packet as dictionary

Tags: python, networking, wireshark, wireshark-dissector, pyshark

I'm trying to read all parameters within the packet. Using **cap[0].layer._all_fields** able to get fields of particular layer/protocol. Looking for something similar say **cap[0]._all_fields**

Comment: What data are you trying to extract that you're not getting with `cap[0]._all_fields`?

Answer (score -2):

Use `dir(cap[0])` and you have it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This will get all attributes on the object, not just the fields.